# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null at XMLHttpRequest.getData

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the code/functions I am trying to run:

```
function loadXMLDoc(cart)
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {
        xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {
        xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xhttp.open("GET",cart,false);
    xhttp.send();
    return xhttp.responseXML;
}

function getData()
{   
    if ((xhr.readyState == 4) &&(xhr.status == 200))
        {   
            var serverResponse = xhr.responseXML;
            var header = serverResponse.getElementsByTagName("book");
            var spantag = document.getElementById("cart");
            var x;
            spantag.innerHTML = "";
            x = "<table cellpadding='1' cellspacing='6' border='0'>";
            x += "<tr><td>Title</td><td>ISBN</td><td>Qty</td><td>Total</td><td>Remove</td></tr>";
            for (i=0; i<header.length; i++)
            {  
                var id =  header[i].getElementsByTagName("id")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                var total =  header[i].getElementsByTagName("total")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                var title =  header[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                var isbn =  header[i].getElementsByTagName("isbn")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                var qty =  header[i].getElementsByTagName("quantity")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                if(qty=="0")
                {
                    continue;
                }
                x += "<tr>"
                + "<td>" + title + "</td>"
                + "<td>" + isbn + "</td>"
                + "<td>" + qty + "</td>"
                + "<td>" + total + "</td>"
                + "<td>" + "<a href='#' onclick='AddRemoveItem(\"Remove\","+id+");'>Remove Item</a>" + "</td>"
                + "</tr>";

            }
            x += "</table>";
            if (header.length != 0)
                spantag.innerHTML = x;
        }
}
```

Unfortunately I'm getting this error when I try and run it:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null
    at XMLHttpRequest.getData

Which it's pointing to this line: `var header = serverResponse.getElementsByTagName("book");`

I believe there might be something wrong in the loadXMLDoc function.

Any ideas how I could fix this error. 
Thanks

Comment: Do you call a script on the same server/domain? Avoid cross-domain requests!

Comment: The other thing is that `responseXML` requires completely valid XML and probably the correct `Content-Type` in the response headers sent from the server.